# jquery first dialog does not align with the rest of the dialog

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

### Problem

I am building a simple Q&A game where each question is a jQuery dialog.
After answering each question, it will close the current dialog, and open a new dialog for next question.

However, the first dialog always has a different position than the rest of the dialog.

### Attempts to solve the problem

After some troubleshooting, I realized this problem happens only when I include images to each dialog. If I remove all the images, the dialog position will be correct.

I am new to javascript and jquery, and I do not have enough knowledge to solve this problem...

My sample code

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
      .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
    
      .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
      }  
    
      .block {
        text-align: center; /* Center text in .block */
      }    
    
      .img {
      float: center;
      width:  400;
      height: 400;
      background-size: cover;
      }
    
     }
      </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#dialog1" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: true,
          maxWidth:500,
          maxHeight: 600,
          width: 500,
          height: 600,
          buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
              $( "#dialog2" ).dialog("open"),
              $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "No": function() {
              $( "#dialog_d" ).dialog("open");
              current_state = $(this);
              $(this).dialog("close");
            }},
            close: function() {
            }
        });
    
        $( "#dialog2" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          maxWidth:500,
          maxHeight: 600,
          width: 500,
          height: 600,
          buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
              $( "#dialog_d2" ).dialog("open");
            },
            "No": function() {
              $( "#dialog_d" ).dialog("open");
              current_state = $(this);
              $(this).dialog("close");
            }},
            close: function() {
            }
        });
    
    
    
        $( "#dialog_d" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          maxWidth:500,
          maxHeight: 600,
          width: 500,
          height: 600,
          buttons: {
            "Retry": function() {
              $("#dialog2").dialog("open");
              $(this).dialog("close");
              current_state.dialog("open");   
            },
            "Quit": function() {
              $("#dialog_d2").dialog("open");          
              $(this).dialog("close");
            }},
            close: function() {
            }
        });
    
        $( "#dialog_d2" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          maxWidth:500,
          maxHeight: 600,
          width: 500,
          height: 600,
          buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
              $( "#dialog2" ).dialog("open");
              $(this).dialog("close");
              current_state.dialog("open");          
            },
            "No": function() {
              $(this).dialog("close");
              current_state.dialog("open");     
            }},
            close: function() {
            }
        });    
      });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="block" id="dialog1" title="Q1: adjfalkj">
      <img class="img"  src="https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hwan-Gue-Cho/publication/224351698/figure/fig2/AS:571184220524544@1513192338732/A-sample-transparent-CAPTCHA-Image-600-x-400-with-Randomly-Assigned-Text-in-Step-4_Q640.jpg"/>
    </div>  
    
    <div class="block" id="dialog2" title="Q2: adjfalkj">
      <img class="img"  src="https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Torben-Weis/publication/221307223/figure/fig1/AS:651195249065984@1532268454203/A-sample-CAPTCHA-test_Q640.jpg"/>
    </div>  
    
    <div class="block" id="dialog_d" title="Wrong Answer!">
      <img class="img" src="https://t.pimg.jp/063/403/181/5/63403181.jpg"/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="block" id="dialog_d2" title="Thanks for playing">
      <img class="img" src="https://art.pixilart.com/e721a8c0189d55c.png"/>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I ran your code and saw that all dialog has same position. Can you show me a picture?

Comment: May I know what is the correct way to test my code?
Currently, I put the code in a .html file. Then I open the html file in my browser.
I tested with Firefox and safari, and I face the position problem

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi I would like to see how you ran it, because when I run the OP's code, I can confirm the problem. If you tested it on Stack Overflow make sure to run the demo in full page to see it

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I ran in my computer via visual studio. But let me update OP's question as a snippet

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen It is weird. in my computer it is ok and all of them are located in center. I am going to explore what exactly happened :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that on some browser like `FireFox` (everything is OK in chrome last version) `position top` has been changed. For example first dialog has `top:304` and the second one rendered with `top:0`.

So to solve the problem set `top:0` to all dialog, like this:

```
.block {
    text-align: center; /* Center text in .block */
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
      .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
    
      .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
      }  
    
      .block {
        text-align: center; /* Center text in .block */
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
      }    
    
      .img {
      float: center;
      width:  400;
      height: 400;
      background-size: cover;
      }
    
     }
      </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#dialog1" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: true,
          maxWidth:500,
          maxHeight: 600,
          width: 500,
          height: 600,
          buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
              $( "#dialog2" ).dialog("open"),
              $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "No": function() {
              $( "#dialog_d" ).dialog("open");
              current_state = $(this);
              $(this).dialog("close");
            }},
            close: function() {
            }
        });
    
        $( "#dialog2" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          maxWidth:500,
          maxHeight: 600,
          width: 500,
          height: 600,
          buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
              $( "#dialog_d2" ).dialog("open");
            },
            "No": function() {
              $( "#dialog_d" ).dialog("open");
              current_state = $(this);
              $(this).dialog("close");
            }},
            close: function() {
            }
        });
    
    
    
        $( "#dialog_d" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          maxWidth:500,
          maxHeight: 600,
          width: 500,
          height: 600,
          buttons: {
            "Retry": function() {
              $("#dialog2").dialog("open");
              $(this).dialog("close");
              current_state.dialog("open");   
            },
            "Quit": function() {
              $("#dialog_d2").dialog("open");          
              $(this).dialog("close");
            }},
            close: function() {
            }
        });
    
        $( "#dialog_d2" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          maxWidth:500,
          maxHeight: 600,
          width: 500,
          height: 600,
          buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
              $( "#dialog2" ).dialog("open");
              $(this).dialog("close");
              current_state.dialog("open");          
            },
            "No": function() {
              $(this).dialog("close");
              current_state.dialog("open");     
            }},
            close: function() {
            }
        });    
      });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="block" id="dialog1" title="Q1: adjfalkj">
      <img class="img"  src="https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hwan-Gue-Cho/publication/224351698/figure/fig2/AS:571184220524544@1513192338732/A-sample-transparent-CAPTCHA-Image-600-x-400-with-Randomly-Assigned-Text-in-Step-4_Q640.jpg"/>
    </div>  
    
    <div class="block" id="dialog2" title="Q2: adjfalkj">
      <img class="img"  src="https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Torben-Weis/publication/221307223/figure/fig1/AS:651195249065984@1532268454203/A-sample-CAPTCHA-test_Q640.jpg"/>
    </div>  
    
    <div class="block" id="dialog_d" title="Wrong Answer!">
      <img class="img" src="https://t.pimg.jp/063/403/181/5/63403181.jpg"/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="block" id="dialog_d2" title="Thanks for playing">
      <img class="img" src="https://art.pixilart.com/e721a8c0189d55c.png"/>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Still seeing the issue in your snippet

Comment: @OmarSiddiqui in snippet? or your computer? my snippet works correctly

Comment: Snippet. But it seems it worked for OP, so that's good enough :D

Comment: I can confirm in my computer, the problem has been solved.

Comment: Just a side question. Since most dialogs always have the same `yes` and `no` buttons with the same functionality (`yes` button advances to the next dialog). I wonder if there is something like class inheritance like in python? So that I can inheritance the same `yes` and `no` button from a single mother class.

Comment: @RavenCheuk honestly I don't know there is base template for jQuery dialog or not. you can ask another question and some other people who has experienced with this can help you